# r - Extract data from vcf file

Tags: r, file, genetics, genome

I analyzed DNA sequences in a bioinformatics pipeline to identify genetic variants of my samples. The effects of these variants have been estimated using the software snpEff. It returns a vcf file like [this example file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NzAkngXs8VUog_Jhyl0jrq1egtgNnG8J/view?usp=sharing).

Since I have a multitude of those vcf files, I'd like to read in the vcf files and extract data from the annotation field (ANN=). The problem I have is that every line after the header contains an ANN field, but the number of annotations can vary from line to line. Thus, I'm looking for a simple way to convert the annotation subfields into a list of data frames (one row for every annotation, columns for the annotation subfields).

I'd be happy if you'd help and suggest a way on how to succeed in extracting the annotation info. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: How exactly are you reading in the data to R? Are you using a package like [vcfR](https://knausb.github.io/vcfR_documentation/)?

Comment: @MrFlick I've tried different options. Yes, I already tried vcfR. However, bedr::read.vcf seems to be a bit ore hany to me. Nevertheless, I'm open to other ways (e.g. readLines, read.table, etc.)